# how to return "true" or false using recursive function?

Tags: python, recursion, boolean

Here is my code:

```
def mirror(s,s2):

 
  new=""
  if s=="":
      return s


      
  new = mirror(s[1:],s2) +s[0]
  
  if len(new)==len(s2):
  
      if new==s2:
          
              return True
      else:
          
              return False
     

def main():

 print(mirror("dcba","abcd"))

 
main()
```

Comment: What have you tried so far and what is it doing wrong? What programming language are you even using? Also take a look at this FAQ: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Comment: I'm using python, I'm trying to solve this problem: "Write a recursive boolean function that takes two strings and checks if one is a reflection of the other."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Programmers new to recursion tend to make the problem harder than necessary and don't trust recursion to do the work for them.  For this problem to make sense recursion-wise, you need to check one character from each string, then decide to declare them different, or recurse down the strings doing the same until you run out of characters (base case.)  Something like:

```
def mirror(s1, s2):

    if not s1 or not s2:  # base case
        return not s1 and not s2  # if both empty, success!

    if s1[0] != s2[-1]:  # compare opposite ends
        return False

    return mirror(s1[1:], s2[:-1])  # recurse on remaining strings
```

Answer (score -1):

If you structure your recursive function like the following you should find some success.

```
recurs() {
  if (finalCondition) return true
  if (isReflection) {
    return recurs()
  }
  else {
    return false
  }
}
```

The idea being that you recurse through the string, checking for the end condition first. Likely this will be an empty string or something like that. Then you check to see if the reflection condition still holds. If it does, you keep recursing, if not you return `false`. When you return `false`, it will propagate all the way back up to the initial call. Likewise, if you reach the end condition, and it returns true, that means you looked over the entirety of the strings and they satisfied the reflection requirement and `true` will propagate.